# Having issue in my side menu bar fixed and content scroll able

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, fixed

Here is my JS fiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/kodi/d2s3uja0/1/

Having issue in my side menu bar fixed and content scrollable. Now I want to show the menu vertical in the left side bar like this

```
M
E
N
U
```

How do I do it in CSS. After I click that, JQuery toggle should work.

I am trying to achieve like this: [wholefoodsmarket](http://www.wholefoodsmarket.com/)

Comment: can any one  guide me How to solve this?

Comment: I have another doubt also instead of  text menu I want to put image  there  using  jquery  slideToggle i done the menu, but In wholefoodsmarket the menu is coming from left to right.How to achieve this. You can see my code in live also http://vkacademy.in/yes/ and click the menu in left side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the css transition and put the `#menu` outside of the view and just toggle class on click of `#menu_btn`.

**HTML**

```
<div id="header">
<div id="wrapper">
<div id="menu_btn" style="float:left;"><a href="#" style="color:#FFFFFF;">Menu</a></div>
<div id="whole">
<div id="wleft">
<ul id="menu">
<li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#">About  Yes Service</a>
<ul id="submenu">
<li><a href="#">Web Design</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Web Development</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Network</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Boys Uniforms</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Girls Uniforms</a><ul id="submenu">
<li><a href="#">T-shirt</a></li>
</ul></li>
<li><a href="#">Thin client</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul></div><!--endofwleft-->
</div><!--endofwhole-->
</div><!--endofmenu-->    
</div><!--endofwrapper-->
</div><!--endofheader-->
```

**CSS**

```
@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */


*{
margin:0px;
padding:0px;
}


#header{
width:100%;
height:60px;
background-color:#031f2d;   
}
#wrapper
{
width:1300px;
height:auto;
margin:auto;
}


#whole
{
width:1300px;
height:1000px;
float:left;
}



#wleft ul
{
width:200px;
height:auto;
float:left;
position:fixed;

outline: 1px solid;
}








#wleft  #menu li
{
width:200px;
height:30px;
float:left;
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#000000
}

#wleft  #menu li a{
color:#FFFFFF;
background-color:#000000;
text-decoration:none;
}

#menu li
{
position:relative;
}

#menu li #submenu 
{
position:absolute;
}


#menu li #submenu
{
display:none;
}

#menu li:hover  #submenu
{
display:block;
position:absolute;
margin-left:200px;
}

#menu li:hover  #submenu li a 
{
border:#CCCCCC 1px solid;
height:25px;
width:300px;
background-color:#031f2d;
color:#fff;
display:block;
padding-top:5px;
}

#menu li:hover  #submenu li a 
{
text-align:left;
text-decoration:none;
}

#submenu li:hover{
background-color:#333333;
}
#menu_btn {
    transform: rotateZ(-90deg);
    position: relative;
    top: 22px;
    left: -5px;
}
#menu {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50px;
    left: -220px;
    transition: left 0.5s ease-out;
}
#menu.shown {
    left:0;
}
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
        $('#menu_btn').click(function(e) {
            $('#menu').toggleClass('shown');
        });
    });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/farskid/eh7pfu33/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have a doubt instead of menu text I want to bring image there.(that means company logo).how do we do that. I am unable to get the answer in jsfiddle, I tested in local it is working for me

Comment: Just replace MENU text with an image, in case you need help comment here. If the answer helped you please accept it.

Comment: could  you please bring me  when mouse hover to the achor tag the background and  submenu background color is changing to white and submenu menu width is big . what we have done is  ok but my client is looking  like this http://www.wholefoodsmarket.com/

Comment: yes Your answer is correct I accepted. how do I bring when  mouse hover to the achor tag the background and submenu background color is changing to white and submenu menu width is big  what we have done is ok ,but my client is looking like this wholefoodsmarket.com .please the menu in this site. If you help me It great for me

Comment: for the mouse hover event you don't need jQuery, simply use :hover pseudo selector in css. for example, #menu > li > a:hover {background-color:#fff; color:#333};

Comment: HI Have you tested the pseudo selector , It is not reflecting me , if we mouseover ,The menu in   wholefoodsmarket.com  is facing vertical image, Which property I have use in css transition and You can see the vertical image is sticking on clicking menu , how do I bring  like that, and another doubt about submenu background How do i increase the width like wholefoodsmarket.com, atleast I try to project like that if we finish another 5 % it is ok to tell to my client , because the client is urging me

Comment: I'll make a complete fiddle of what you want and link it here. give me some amount of time though.

Comment: Sure,Yes please , You already got  the concept ,I want the menu and submenu reflecting like wholefoodsmarket.com.  I trust you. I leave to you I will do the remaining work in the project. I will be waiting for you

Comment: You can always  check in my link. How we are going to implement the menu in my client site, http://vkacademy.in/yes/  I will do  rest of my work. But it is very very urgent deadline for me. I hope you understood my position.

Comment: Once You Finish Kindly update in fiddle. Thanks for your knowledge

Comment: Farzad I am waiting for you.

Comment: @webResource I will add it my friend

Comment: Sure, thanks so much  what I have  tried and uploaded today http://www.vkacademy.in/yes1/  but menu not done.

Comment: Farzad .You Said I will add. I am waiting please